# Mongoid find using an array field without any order inside the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following records:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54bcc86320db902902000c13"),
    "latest_activity_at" : ISODate("2015-01-19T09:10:40.000Z"),
    "members" : [ 
        "54ad458b20db9004e903ac02", 
        "54ad1d9320db9004e90348b2"
    ],
    "kid_id" : ObjectId("54ad1d9320db9004e90348b2"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-01-19T09:10:40.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-01-19T09:03:31.000Z"),
    "token" : "cvq1t-Ml7HLmzQo3mDMdiA"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54bcca7b20db902902000e28"),
    "latest_activity_at" : ISODate("2015-01-19T09:12:27.000Z"),
    "members" : [ 
        "54ad1d9320db9004e90348b2", 
        "54ad458b20db9004e903ac02"
    ],
    "kid_id" : ObjectId("54ad458b20db9004e903ac02"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-01-19T09:12:27.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-01-19T09:12:27.000Z"),
    "token" : "H4Sv2yqXSpdGIsKlD7zsRg"
}
```

And I'm trying to find the record using the following method:

## model

```
 def message_between_users(member, member2)
        conversation = KidConversation.any_of(members: [member.to_s, member2.to_s] )
        conversation.count
      end
```

## view

```
= current_kid.message_between_users(current_kid.id.to_s, k.id.to_s)
```

but I only get one record, I would like to find all records, no matter the order inside the array field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will search inside array fields for you so you want to say:

> where `members` is `current_kid.id.to_s` and `members` is `k.id.to_s`.

The underlying query you're trying to build is:

```
db.kid_conversations.find({
  $and: [
    { members: "54ad458b20db9004e903ac02" },
    { members: "54ad1d9320db9004e90348b2" }
  ]
})
```

You want to use `all_of` with two clauses:

```
KidConversation.all_of(
  { members: member.to_s },
  { members: member2.to_s }
)
```

or build the `$and` yourself with `where`:

```
KidConversation.where(:$and => [
  { :members => member.to_s  },
  { :members => member2.to_s }
])
```

---

You could also use [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/):

> The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

Thanks to [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) for the reminder about this. In MongoDB terms, you could:

```
db.kid_conversations.find({
  members: {
    $all: [
      "54ad458b20db9004e903ac02",
      "54ad1d9320db9004e90348b2"
    ]
  }
})
```

That translates to one of these in Mongoid:

```
KidConversation.where(:members.all => [ member, member2 ].map(&:to_s))
KidConversation.all(:members => [ member, member2 ].map(&:to_s))
```

Both of those Mongoid queries end up the same when they get to MongoDB so use whichever version makes sense to you.

Comment: Why not use [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) ?Considering it's the same field in the argument that is. That's a lot less terse than naming the same field each time.